# How to check if php built-in server is running

Tags: php, web-server

Recent versions of PHP has a built-in webserver (for non-production environments) that can be started with `php -S [...]`.

How can I check if it's already running on the server before attempting to start it?

I realise that the hacky way would be to try to start it and look out for the error message `Failed to listen on [...]`, but I thought there might be a cleaner way :-)

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that ultimately I'd like to be able to check this in a script and only start the server if it's not already started. I also forgot to mention that I'm looking for a solution for Linux, but Windows solutions are of course welcome as well, in case someone else will be looking for that one day :-)

Comment: What about `ps`?

Comment: Yes, or sending a request to the server and see if it responds...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my edit to Paolo's answer was rejected, here's a more complete answer:

`ps aux | grep php`

This command will output something like the following if php is currently running:

```
pi        3245  0.0  0.5  21400  2416 pts/0    S    Jan29   0:02 php -S localhost:8000 -t /path/to/php/docroot
pi        3518  0.0  0.3   5220  1712 pts/0    S+   00:42   0:00 grep --color=auto php
```

The second line can be ignored as it's just self-referencing the search command.
This script will check if the server is running and start it if it's not:

```
if ! ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -qs 'php -S localhost:8000';
then
  php -S localhost:8000 -t /path/to/php/docroot &>/dev/null &
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

As Michael Hampton already suggested, a command like `ps aux | grep php` will reveal if PHP's webserver is already up.

Comment: `ps aux | grep php` returns two lines, one of which contain the complete command used to invoke the php server.

Comment: Was that what you wanted or did you want to check this in a script?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the ultimate idea – which I didn't mention – was to check this in a script. I've been working on the script but didn't manage to make it work yet, and forgot to update this question/answer in the meantime. If this answer can be edited to include a simple script to check it and only start the server if it's not started, I will mark it as the answer, ok? :-)